# Angular 6 FormArray send as array

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, api, typescript

I have Reactive Forms on my site which uses FormBuilder.

I have two fields which have `FormControl`s and an array of fields created by user that is `FormArray`.

When I sent data to the server it turned out that `FormArray` sends instead of array a string with listed items with comma.

How could I send data to the server using array?

That is my class methods

```
formGroup = this.fb.group({
    link: [null, [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern(/^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/)
    ]],
    image: [null, Validators.required],
    features: this.fb.array([this.fb.control('', Validators.required)])
  });

beforeSubmit(): FormData {
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('link', this.link.value);
    formData.append('image', this.image.value);
    formData.append('features', this.features.value);

    return formData;
  }

  submit() {
    console.log('submit');

    const formData = this.beforeSubmit() as FormData;

    this.ss.postSite(formData).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
      }
    );

  }
```

and service

```
postSite(input: FormData) {
    console.log('posting');

    return this.http.post<Site>(this.API_URL, input, this.HEADERS).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please provide the function that users add the fields to array

Comment: it just pushes empty FormControl to the features array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

`formData.append('features', this.features.value);` changed to

```
this.features.getRawValue().forEach(e => {
  formData.append('features[]', e);
});
```

Thus we iterate over `rawValue`s which are an array.

Answer (score -2):

It`s not FormArray problem. FormData map array to string.
Try to use this solution.

```
submit() {
   console.log('submit');
   const formData = this.formGroup.value;

   this.ss.postSite(formData).subscribe(
     response => {
       console.log(response);
     }
   );

 }
```

Use FormData when you need to send file with `<input type="file" />`

Answer (score -2):

> A FormArray aggregates the values of each child FormControl into an
>   array

You have to push FormControls as per iuser input into FormArray. If you are doing so already, please share that code part